# Springboot app settings to perform StressTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jmeter, stress-testing

i want to ask about what's the proper settings on springboot application properties to perform a stress test? because i'm constantly getting this error from my Jmeter when it reach 16k samples on my springboot rest server, also i am doing 100thread/s on the jmeter thread group for 5 minutes. Thank you

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you've run out of outbound ports.

Check your operating system documentation regarding how to either increase them and/or or reduce recycle time.

Example suggestions can be found i.e. in [Solved “java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect” issue on Windows](https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/) or [Handling "exhausting available ports" in Jmeter](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/handling-exhausting-available-ports-jmeter-shrikant-m/)

Alternatively you can allocate another machine and consider switching to [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)